# How should I estimate the variance using a sample (not knowing the mean)?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, sample, mse

The unadjusted sample variance is biased, yet it has a smaller mean squared error.

Also, if we assume the sample comes from a normal distribution, the maximum likelihood estimator for the variance is the unadjusted sample variance.

So what practical good is the adjusted sample variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing inference on the mean for data from a normal distribution then the ratio of the estimated mean (minus the true mean, i.e. null hypothesis is true) to the standard error (using the $n-1$ adjustment) follows a t-distribution which can then be used for inference (significance tests, confidence intervals).  If you don't use the adjustment then the ratio does not follow the t-distribution.  For large sample sizes the difference may be negligible (but so are the advantages of the unadjusted variance), but for small samples this could throw off the inference.  Also for regression, anova, and other inferences the adjustment is more than just subtracting 1, so not adjusting will have a larger consequence in those cases.

If you are interested in the variance directly, then minimizing the MSE may be the most important consideration, but usually the variance is more of a nuisance parameter that is not as interesting for its own sake, but a step to another statistic (test statistic, confidence interval) that is of interest.  In these cases issues like unbiasedness and independence are more important than finding the maximum likelihood or minimizing the mean squared error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what do you mean with "minus the true mean"? What does that have to do with the null hypothesis being true?

Comment: @Rodrigo, the standard formula for the 1 sample t test is $t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}}$ where $s$ is the square root of the variance using $n-1$.  If $\mu_0$ is the true mean of the normal distribution then this statistic follows a t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.  If we know the exact value of the true mean then there really is no need for doing this inference, so more often $\mu_0$ is a statement of the null hypothesis and we talk about the distribution assuming that the null is true.